# Latex Commands with URL

Tags: latex, tex, pdflatex, cls

I am having trouble adding a URL to the Linkedin command. I want it to essentially print the Linkedin logo, text that I want to be explicitly seen, and a URL that the user will be redirected to upon clicking it. Below is the current .cls file.

.cls file:

```
\newcommand{\linkedinsymbol}{\faLinkedin}
\newcommand{\printinfo}[2]{\mbox{\textcolor{accent}{\normalfont #1}\hspace{0.5em}#2\hspace{2em}}}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\newcommand{\linkedin}[1]{\printinfo{\linkedinsymbol}{#1}}
```

I tried turning the last line into the following:

```
\newcommand{\linkedin}[2]{\printinfo{\linkedinsymbol}{#1}}{\url{#2}}
```

However, upon doing so, I get the following errors:

```
! LaTeX Error: Missing \begin{document}.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...

l.91 ...{\printinfo{\linkedinsymbol}{#1}}{\url{#2}
                                                  }
?
! Undefined control sequence.
\hyper@linkurl ...tionraw >>}\relax \Hy@colorlink
                                                  \@urlcolor #1\Hy@xspace@en...
l.91 ...{\printinfo{\linkedinsymbol}{#1}}{\url{#2}
                                                  }
?
! Undefined control sequence.
\close@pdflink ->\Hy@endcolorlink
                                  \Hy@VerboseLinkStop \pdfendlink
l.91 ...{\printinfo{\linkedinsymbol}{#1}}{\url{#2}
                                                  }
?
```

**Minimum Reproducible Example:**

main.tex:

```
\PassOptionsToPackage{dvipsnames}{xcolor}
\documentclass[10pt,letterpaper]{altacv}
\geometry{left=1cm,right=9cm,marginparwidth=6.8cm,marginparsep=1.2cm,top=1.25cm,bottom=1.25cm,footskip=2\baselineskip}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[default]{lato}

\usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref}

\begin{document}
\linkedin{linkedin.com/in/varunjain-me}{www.linkedin.com/in/varunjain-me}
\end{document}
```

.cls file:

```
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}[1995/12/01]
\@ifl@t@r\fmtversion{2018/04/01}{\UseRawInputEncoding}{}
\ProvidesClass{altacv}[2018/07/27 AltaCV v1.1.4, yet another alternative class for a résumé/curriculum vitae.]

\newif\if@academicons
\DeclareOption{academicons}{\@academiconstrue}
\newif\if@normalphoto
\DeclareOption{normalphoto}{\@normalphototrue}
\DeclareOption*{\PassOptionsToClass{\CurrentOption}{extarticle}}
\ProcessOptions\relax

\LoadClass{extarticle}

\RequirePackage[margin=2cm]{geometry}
\RequirePackage{fontawesome}

\if@academicons
  \ExplSyntaxOn
  \msg_redirect_name:nnn { fontspec } { font-not-found } { none }
  \ExplSyntaxOff
  \RequirePackage{academicons}
  \newfontfamily{\AI}{academicons.ttf}
\fi

\RequirePackage{xcolor}

\colorlet{accent}{blue!70!black}
\colorlet{heading}{black}
\colorlet{emphasis}{black}
\colorlet{body}{black!80!white}
\newcommand{\itemmarker}{{\small\textbullet}}
\newcommand{\ratingmarker}{\faCircle}

\RequirePackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}
\RequirePackage[skins]{tcolorbox}
\RequirePackage{enumitem}
\setlist{leftmargin=*,labelsep=0.5em,nosep,itemsep=0.25\baselineskip,after=\vskip0.25\baselineskip}
\setlist[itemize]{label=\itemmarker}
\RequirePackage{graphicx}
\RequirePackage{etoolbox}
\RequirePackage{dashrule}
\RequirePackage{multirow,tabularx}
\RequirePackage{changepage}

\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
\newcommand{\divider}{\textcolor{body!30}{\hdashrule{\linewidth}{0.6pt}{0.5ex}}\medskip}

\newenvironment{fullwidth}{%
  \begin{adjustwidth}{}{\dimexpr-\marginparwidth-\marginparsep\relax}}
  {\end{adjustwidth}}
\newcommand{\linkedinsymbol}{\faLinkedin}
\newcommand{\printinfo}[2]{\mbox{\textcolor{accent}{\normalfont #1}\hspace{0.5em}#2\hspace{2em}}}
\newcommand{\linkedin}[2]{\printinfo{\linkedinsymbol}{#1}}{\url{#2}}
```

Comment: Can you please make a [mre]?

Comment: I added one in.

Comment: This is not *minimal*; it has too much unrelated code. It's also not reproducible, `\addbibresource` is not defined. When I comment that out, the code produces a pdf without showing any errors. I use pdfTeX 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.18 (TeX Live 2017/Debian). Please try again. See [ask].

Comment: My mistake, I put the version I am currently using which has no errors but also doesn't yield the intended result. I fixed that up.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is the code that ended up working for my scenario:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{fontawesome}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\colorlet{accent}{blue!70!black}

\begin{document}
\newcommand{\linkedinsymbol}{\faLinkedin}
% \newcommand{\printinfo}[2]{\mbox{\textcolor{accent}{\normalfont #1}\hspace{0.5em}#2\hspace{2em}}}
\newcommand{\weblinks}[3]{\mbox{\textcolor{accent}{\normalfont #1}\hspace{0.5em}{\href{#2}{#3}}\hspace{2em}}}
% \newcommand{\linkedin}[2]{\printinfo{\linkedinsymbol}{#1}{\url{#2}}}
\newcommand{\linkedin}[2]{\weblinks{\linkedinsymbol}{#1}{#2}}

\linkedin{http://linkedin.com/in/varunjain-me}{linkedin.com/in/varunjain}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you so much! This helped a lot!!! i was stuck for so long!!

Answer (score 0):

This minimal example works for me:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{fontawesome}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\colorlet{accent}{blue!70!black}

\begin{document}
\newcommand{\linkedinsymbol}{\faLinkedin}
\newcommand{\printinfo}[2]{\mbox{\textcolor{accent}{\normalfont #1}\hspace{0.5em}#2\hspace{2em}}}
\newcommand{\linkedin}[2]{\printinfo{\linkedinsymbol}{#1}{\url{#2}}}

\linkedin{linkedin.com/in/varunjain-me}{www.linkedin.com/in/varunjain-me}
\end{document}
```

At least it produces some output... I don't know what exactly you expect, but you can probably take it from here.

Comment: I wasn't looking for this particular output, but I was able to get it thanks to this. I found out the reason it did not work was because I did not include http://.

Comment: @VarunJain Glad to hear that. If you think others could benefit from your answer, feel free to answer your own question.